# why is this R code for a t-sne analysis running so slowly

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a t-sne analysis on a file with 39772 columns and 170 rows.
I first used the "Rtsne" package, but that package seems to have a limit of 10,000 columns as R keeps aborting every time I run the code with the entire file.

Because of this, I changed the package to "tsne" instead of "Rtsne" but now the code is taking FOREVER to run (like over 2 hours). This is what I have so far...I've read other posts but nothing seems to apply to my problem. I'd appreciate any ideas on what I can do to fix this and actually see an output.

CODE USING "TSNE" PACKAGE (taking 2+ hours to run...still haven't seen an output):

```
exp =read.csv("tsnedata.csv")
library(tsne)
exp1=t(exp)
exp2=matrix(as.numeric(unlist(exp1)),nrow=nrow(exp1))
exp3=data.matrix(exp2)
cols=rainbow(10)
ecb=function(x,y){plot(x, t='n'); text(x, col=cols);}
tsne_res=tsne(exp3, epoch_callback=ecb, perplexity=50, epoch=50)
```

ORIGINAL CODE USING "RTSNE" PACKAGE (this is the code that immediately causes R to abort unless I run the code using only the first 10,000 columns of the data):

```
exp<- read.csv("tsnedata.csv")
library(Rtsne)
exp1=t(exp)
exp2=matrix(as.numeric(unlist(exp1)),nrow=nrow(exp1))
exp3 <- data.matrix(exp2)
tsne <- Rtsne(as.matrix(exp3), check_duplicates = FALSE, pca = FALSE, perplexity=30, theta=0.5, dims=2)

cols <- rainbow(10)
plot(tsne$Y, t='n')
text(tsne$Y, col=cols)
```

Comment: Try profiling your code: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html. If your code spends the most time on `tsne(exp3...`, it'll be difficult to speed up your code without recoding `tsne`

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with scRNAseq data and want to visualize each cell as each dot on tsne visualization, here are my thoughts:
1. Make sure your input is cell by gene expression matrix.
2. Do dimension reduction first(e.g PCA), only feed in the first few principal components into Rtsne.

Rtsne is based on Barnes-Hut implementation, it is much faster than original implementation of tsne, and also a better way to do tsne analysis as well(as it corrected some bugs from the original tsne package). However, from my experience, tsne outputs cuter (round shape, ball-like) visualization than Rtsne.